# Merge two Arrays and sort by created_at Video and Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, join, concatenation, each

I'm new to Ruby so I trying hard to do this,I'm trying to unite these two arrays to have videos and images mixed by date, the way it is, the shots will always be on top of the videos.

In the controller I have

```
@videos = Video.all.order("created_at desc")
@shots = Shot.all.order("created_at desc")
```

and in the view

```
   <% @shots.each do | shot| %>
    <%= render shot %>
   <% end %>

  <% @videos.each do | shot| %>
    <%= render video %>
   <% end %>
```

how do I put these two arrays together in order of time, to have shots and videos together?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, for instance:

**Controller**

```
@resources = Video.order(created_at: :desc) | Shot.order(created_at: :desc)
```

**View**

```
<%= render @resources %>
```

You should then have a partial named `_resource.html.erb` in that case

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error at /
Missing partial videos/_video with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: what happens if you create the videos/_video partial and shots/_shot partial instead?

Comment: undefined method `url' for #<Shot:0x00007fdd6acc2758>
                  <%= link_to video, class: "video" do %>
                    <%= get_video_iframe(video.url) %>
                    <% end %>